# Exclude fields from Superclass in Cloud Firestore serialization?

Tags: android, serialization, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore and some of my classes extend from an external library (only read access).
When an object is saved to Firestore all fields from the Superclass are included too. 
I have found the @Exclude and @IgnoreExtraProperties annotations. However since I have only read access to the superclass I cant include them in my code.

Is there any way of completely "ignoring" the superclass in serialisation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in which you can ignore the fields that are inherited from a SuperClass. Because you only have read access you cannot add/change the `annotations` from your SuperClass.

What can you do is to ask the owner of the SuperClass to change the fields from public to `private`. In this way, you only be able to access them trough setters and getters and the fields will not be inherited anymore.